# Outlook add-in added to my outlook express even before creating installer

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create an outlook 2010 add-in using c#. I created a project and a form with some buttons, added some functionality to it and compiled. I have started the form on Startup as shown below,

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SndRcvFrm frm = new SndRcvFrm(this.Application);
    frm.Show();
}
```

So far so good. When i tried to open my outlook, it was actually loading the add-in and even the form was shown. I was wondering how this happened. I have not created any installer to install this add-in, even i have not added any reference anywhere. How did outlook automatically detected my add-in and started it. Then i removed the add-in from the add-in manager of outlook. Next time onwards, the add-in was not loaded.

My question is, if installer/clickonce is the only way to add add-in to outlook, how did my add-in appear in outlook even before installing it. In that case, during my development stage is it possible to add my add-in to outlook and see it in action without actually installing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your addin using Visual Studio, Visual Studio is kind enough to register the addin on your machine for you, so you can run it and debug it on your machine.

When you want to deploy it to another machine you will need to create a setup/installer using either ClickOnce or traditional setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guessed it. Right now i have removed the add-in from outlook, so after that the add-in doesn't appear. So is there any way to add the add-in again to the outlook in my development system? In any way will the visual studio re-register again? because how many times ever i recompile the solution it is not getting added.

Comment: Got it. When we run the project it automatically registers it, so that we can debug. Thanks for your information.